# Trouble with sub-menu and overlapping body element

Tags: css

I'm helping a client with her website and ran into a problem.

On the responsive version of our menu, when I hover over a menu item with a few sub-menu items, those menu items display, but an element below is showing through the text as well.

The offending element is a testimonial slider that is dynamically updated, so I'm guessing that has something to do with it.

Here's a GIF: [overlap problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUSVn.gif)

Here's a link to the site: http://gogift.com.au/wordpress/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Hey, Paul. If you really want to get to the bottom of it, try creating a small example with the minimum amount of code to reproduce it in - say, a jsFiddle or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the z-index of the `.header-row` element. Because it is positioned relative and so it's z-index is the one that counts.

This is the header-row now:

```
.header-row {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

change it to:

```
.header-row {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

you could also set the .header-row to `position:static` and then change the z-index of the `#main-nav`element:

```
.header-row {
    position: static;
    z-index: 2;
}

#main-nav {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: As there is some confusion I want to add a bit more to this answer:

The navigation is in front of the content because there is no z-index set for the `<div id="content">`and it's children. So any element with a z-index defined will be in front of the content.

As the header-row has a z-index of 2 - the nav is in front of the content.

The problem is that the testimonial-slides have a dynamic set z-index between 90 and 100. As they have no parent with a defined z-index and relative position this z-index will be matched against the .header-row's z-index which is only 2.

One more alternative to solve the problem would be to set the z-index of `<div id="content">` to 1.

Comment: The existing z-index is fine - you can actually see the the submenu is appearing over the rest of the page so it isn't been pushed below the other elements. The problem is that it you can see through it, which is because the background is transparent.

Comment: @FluffyKitten that is not the case. The parent element with the id menu-main has a background color set. I will write a bit more about the z-index in the post above.

Comment: But if the z-index was the problem, you wouldn't be able to see the menu at all?

Comment: Sorry, you're right... its the z-index of the testimonals, I didn't realise that was a separate slider and only checked the 1st one.

Comment: I just saw your comment & edit now - yes, thanks for the clarification! I'd suggest going lower than 2000 with the header-row z-index though, just in case a modal or anything that show be absolutely on top has a lower z-index. :-)

Comment: huda, I ended up setting #content's z-index to 1, and that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's one of two things: either the z-index of the menu isn't high enough or the background of the menu items is transparent.